# edmgen.exe user defined functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been trying to automate my EDMX generation using a batch file using edmgen.exe and edmgen2.exe however when I use edmgen.exe it doesn't generate any user defined functions.  I have searched and searched like crazy; just can't find a solution.

My usage is as follows:
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:fullgeneration /connectionstring:"Data Source=localhost\sql2008r2; Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI" /project:Project /entitycontainer:test /namespace:myns /language:CSharp

EDMGEN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb387165.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to import functions using EdmGen. The way the designer imports function is by using the DDEX provider from VS and this is not available in the .NET Framework by itself.